# replacing double switch old cable colours

Tags: walls, switch

I'm having trouble replacing an old dimmer switch with a normal on/off double switch.
One switch is for the ceiling light and the other is for two wall lights inside the living room, the cabling is 3 wires red, yellow, blue and an earth is connected to the back box.
I thought that I could just rewire into the new switch as it is in the old but the terminal connections are different on the new switch.
There is nothing written on the old connections to help.
[image: old]

[image: new]

Am I right in thinking, on the new switch as you look at the terminals, I put red wire from the wall into the furthest right terminal, the blue from wall into next furthest right terminal, the yellow into either of the remaining terminals and the red loop wire into both Comm terminals?.

Thanks in advance.

Pete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need the red wire into one of the COM terminals, with the red loop from there to the other COM terminal. Then the yellow wire into one of the 1 way terminals and the blue wire into the other 1 way terminal.

Leave the red tape on the blue and yellow wires to show that they are switched live.

Comment: Followed your instructions and it works perfectly, although I did strip the head of one of the terminal screws as it was really tough to tighten up, bought a new one and everything is fine. Thank you.